# javascript minesweeper floodfill algorithm not working as it should

Tags: javascript, algorithm, minesweeper

I'm trying to write my first simple minesweeper game. For revealing empty fields I wrote a simple flood fill algorithm, however it isn't working as it should. Here's a snippet of code:

```
function reveal(a,b){
var fieldId = getFieldId(a,b);  

/*
cells are stored in array fields[]. Each cell is an object {x: x,y: y, hasBomb: boolean,
hasBeenDiscovered: boolean}. Function getFieldId returns array key for (x,y) cell.
*/

if(a < 0 || a > boardWidth-1){return}
if(b < 0 || b > boardHeight-1){return}

if(fields[fieldId].hasBeenDiscovered == true){return}

if(getNeighbourNumber(a,b) > 0){
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).innerHTML = getNeighbourNumber(a,b);
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).setAttribute('discovered',1);
    fields[fieldId].hasBeenDiscovered = true;
    return
}else if(getNeighbourNumber(a,b) == 0){
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).innerHTML = ' ';
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById(a+'x'+b).setAttribute('discovered',1);  
    fields[fieldId].hasBeenDiscovered = true;


}

    reveal(a,b);
    console.log('0 ' + '0');
    reveal(a+1,b);
    console.log('+1' + ' ' + '0');
    reveal(a-1,b);
    console.log('-1 ' + '0');
    reveal(a,b+1);
    console.log('0 ' + '+1');
    reveal(a,b-1);
    console.log('0 ' + '-1');
    reveal(a-1,b-1);
    console.log('-1 ' + '-1');
    reveal(a-1,b+1);
    console.log('-1 ' + '+1');
    reveal(a+1,b+1);
    console.log('+1 ' + '+1');
    reveal(a+1,b-1);
    console.log('+1 ' + '-1');
    console.log('------------');

}
```

When discovering empty cell which north, northwest and west neighbours has neighbours bombs, floodfill reveal just those cells, even if other neighbours (south, south east west, east, northeast) are empty. I'm beginner coder and I can't figure out why this code isn't fully working. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: console logs were put in just for debug attempt.

Comment: would you create jsfiddle please

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/cmn2u1hk/

Comment: Hey would you draw a small sample diagram, what is the exact issue? I mean when user clicks on one cell, then what is happening, and what should be happening? for an instance you can take static data rather than bombs and can explain me issue, or create 4x4 or 5x5 matrix and try to explain

Comment: What I have understand from your question is, assume that this image is a field -> http://stanford.library.sydney.edu.au/archives/spr2007/entries/consciousness-representational/NumberedGrid1.jpg .... then if I click on 5 and if all 9 items are without bombs then it should happen ... at the moment only 1,2, and 4 is opening, right?

Comment: Almost yes. If user has clicked 5 on your cellgrid. If all surrounding cells has 0 bombs in their neighbourhood, then all cells surrounding cells are revealed and algorithm works fine. Problem starts when cells 1, 2, 4 has one or more bomb in their vicinity (so instead of being fully revealed, they should reveal a number), algorithm works just for those cells (so on cell 1, 2, 4 number will appear) but not for cells 3, 6, 7, 8, 9 - even if they has no bombs in their vicinity and algorithm should reveal them and explore further. Sorry for my poor english, but it's not my native language.

Comment: if it answers your question than accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am happy to say that you wrote an awesome code it was so easy to read and understand the code.

You just need to check a small thing in the revealField function, Here one thing you need to remember is when you get value from the attribute it will give you in string always, so you need to parse the string to number with the decimal base.

```
function revealField(){
    var x = this.getAttribute('x');
    var y = this.getAttribute('y');
    x = parseInt(x, 10);
    y = parseInt(y, 10);

    var fieldId = getFieldId(x,y);

    if(fields[fieldId].hasBomb == true){
        document.getElementById(x+'x'+y).innerHTML = 'B';
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'brown';
        this.setAttribute('hasBomb', 1);
        removeEvents();
        alert('Bomba! Przegrales!');
    }else{
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        this.setAttribute('discovered',1);
        reveal(x,y);
        if(validateVictory() == true){
            removeEvents();
            alert('Brawo! Odkryles wszystkie bomby!');          
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/cmn2u1hk/1/) aswell

Comment: Thank you for you kind words. And now program works perfectly fine, thank you! However I would like to clarify whether I fully understand why script wasn't working previously - it was working only for cells to left, upper left and up from selected cell because for those cells inside recursive function reveal(a,b) there was no "+" operator, only "-"? And for "+" operator function as parameter took sum of two strings (so reveal(12+1,13) was indeed reveal(121,13), instead of reveal(13,13))? And that wasn't case for "-" operator?

Comment: yup true, whenever you tried to add +1 it was concatenating, rather than adding....